# Find if segment comes within distance of another one

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, categorization

I have a bunch of segments (the data I have are the 2 points that makes the segment [x1,y1] and [x2, y2]) and would like to categorize them according to their position. If a segment is close enough to another one, then I want to put them together. If I had to describe it in sentence: I would like to find all neighbor segments with a distance of 5px away from any point of the segment.

With rules similar to the drawn picture:
[image: picture]

I was looking at different algorithms but most of them deal with intersections and predict whether the lines will intersect. That does not really work for me as I don't want to continue the lines to infinity, I just want to know if they come within 5px of each other.

Does anyone knows how I can approach this problem (and relatively fast)? Do you know any frameworks that could help? (I was looking at the nearest neighbors but I cannot find any framework that deals with geometry instead of points).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I have revised my previous answer. That answer hat some shortcomings. I think my new answer shows a simpler and more robust solution.)

You have two segments, S with points S<sub>0</sub> and S<sub>1</sub> and T with poins T<sub>0</sub> and T<sub>1</sub>. A collision is detected when these segments are less than a distance of *r* apart at one point.

For the segment S, you get the direction vector Δ**s**, the segment length *s* and the normalized direction vector  **u**.

Δ**s** = S<sub>1</sub> − S<sub>0</sub>
       *s* = |Δ**s**|
       **u** = Δ**s** / *s*

The unit vector **u** and the point S<sub>0</sub> can describe a transformation of any point P to a point P′:

P′<sub>x</sub> =   (P<sub>x</sub> − S<sub>0x</sub>) · u<sub>x</sub> + (P<sub>y</sub> − S<sub>0y</sub>) · u<sub>y</sub>
       P′<sub>y</sub> = − (P<sub>x</sub> − S<sub>0x</sub>) · u<sub>y</sub> + (P<sub>y</sub> − S<sub>0y</sub>) · u<sub>x</sub>

In this transformation the points of the segment S are:

S′<sub>0</sub> = (0, 0)
       S′<sub>1</sub> = (*s*, 0)

For the transformed points T′<sub>0</sub> and T′<sub>1</sub>, the y components can be interpreted as signed distance to S. Now several tests can be performed:

- The first test is whether T′<sub>0</sub> or T′<sub>1</sub> are within a distance of *r* of the segment S or within a radius of *r* of either S<sub>0</sub>′ or S<sub>1</sub>′. If so, we have a hit.
- The next test is whether the two lines intersect. That can only happen if the signs of T′<sub>0y</sub> or T′<sub>1y</sub> are different. If so, we have a hit.
- For the last test, we reverse the first test by transforming S to S′′ in a system where T is aligned to the x-axis. Then test whether one of the transformed points S′′<sub>0</sub> or S′′<sub>1</sub> are within *r* of T′′. If so, we have a hit, otherwise it's a miss.

Python code is below. I've also updated my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fe348pkn/).

Notes:

- The longitudinal variable *a* and the distance *d* in my old answer were in effect the same as the x′ and y′ here. I think the transformation is simpler.
- This solution tests only (1) whether the points of T are within a distance of *r* from S, (2) whether the lines intersect and (3) whether the points of S are within a distance of *r* from T. The case of collinear line segments is caught by the tests (1) and (3).
- The code below does not handle zero-length segments (S<sub>0</sub> = S<sub>1</sub> or T<sub>0</sub> = T<sub>1</sub>) explicitly, but returning a non-null vector as norm of a null vector seems to do the trick – tests (1) and (3) catch these cases.

Python code:

```
import math

class Point:
    """ A point P(x, y) in 2D space
    """

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

class Vector:
    """ A vector v(x, y) in 2D space
    """

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def mag(self):
        """ magnitude of the vector
        """
        
        return math.hypot(self.x, self.y)
    
    def norm(self):
        """ return the normalized vector or (0, 0)
        """
    
        a = self.mag()
        
        if a*a < 1.0e-16:
            return Vector(1, 0)
        
        return Vector(self.x / a, self.y / a)
    


def diff(p, q):
    """ difference vector (q - p)
    """

    return Vector(q.x - p.x, q.y - p.y)

def within(p, dx, r):
    """ Is p within r of point (dx, 0)?
    """

    x = p.x - dx
    y = p.y
    
    return x*x + y*y <= r*r

def rot(p, u):
    """ Rotate point p to a coordinate system aligned with u.
    """

    return Point(p.x * u.x + p.y * u.y,
                -p.x * u.y + p.y * u.x)

def collision(s, t, r):
    """ Do the line segments s and t collide with a radius r
    """

    ds = diff(s[0], s[1])
    ss = ds.mag()    
    u = ds.norm()
    
    a0 = rot(diff(s[0], t[0]), u)
    a1 = rot(diff(s[0], t[1]), u)

    # Test T0 and T1 against S
    
    if -r <= a0.y <= r and -r <= a0.x <= ss + r:
        if a0.x < 0: return within(a0, 0, r)
        if a0.x > ss: return within(a0, ss, r)
        return True    
    
    if -r <= a1.y <= r and -r <= a1.x <= ss + r:
        if a1.x < 0: return within(a1, 0, r)
        if a1.x > ss: return within(a1, ss, r)
        return True

    # Test intersection
    
    if a0.y * a1.y < -0.9 * r * r:
        a = -a0.y * (a1.x - a0.x) / (a1.y - a0.y) + a0.x
        
        if 0 <= a <= ss: return True

    # Test S0 and S1 against T
    
    dt = diff(t[0], t[1])
    tt = dt.mag()    
    v = dt.norm()
    
    b0 = rot(diff(t[0], s[0]), v)
    b1 = rot(diff(t[0], s[1]), v)

    if 0 <= b0.x <= tt and -r <= b0.y <= r: return True
    if 0 <= b1.x <= tt and -r <= b1.y <= r: return True
       
    return False
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It is very insightful and helpful. I am playing with your JS Fiddle and I found a case that was not covered by your code: when the segment head are side by side but the heads do not hover the middle of each segments. For example, if you put the lines side by side (in the continuation), similar to " .---.  .---." where "." are the segments heads and "-" the segment bodies. How would you deal with this case? Thanks again!

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that dealing with the heads is pretty easy. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Hm. There's also a problem when the lines are collinear, probably because I don't catch the case where d<sub>0</sub> = d<sub>1</sub>. I didn't check the circle around the tips, because I thought that this case would be caught by the reversed check, but your example isn't.

Comment: I have implemented your solution in Python and have tested it with my dataset. It seems that there is a division by 0 when computing apos and aneg. The Segment coordinates are: S([2834, 813], [2844, 813]) and T([2843, 809], [2855, 809]). 

So it does seem that this collinearity is indeed a problem for me. How would you solve this?

Comment: Yes, there is a problem when d₀ = d₁. I think you can catch that after calculating them and before calcuating apos and aneg. If d₀ = d₁, return true if |d₀| < r and if at least one of a₀ or a₁ is between 0 and s and false otherwise. The reverse check should catch the possibility that a₀ < 0 and  a₁ > s.

Comment: (In Javascript, the division by zero just introduces an NaN and won't throw an error. Python is stricter. Fixing this should be part of the answer, but I don't have time now to implement and test everytjing properly.)

Comment: Thanks for the green tick. If you're still interested, I've rewritten my answer with what I think is a simpler and more robust approach.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll try to rewrite the code in order to compare one line to all other lines at once. Since I am doing the same calculation for each line separately. I'll work with matrices so that ds, ss and u can be done for all lines at the same time. a0 and a1 should be too. My goal would be to return an array of [True, False] for all line. I would then extract the sets according to the returned array. This would improve performance but I will have to deconstruct the Point and Vector classes. I'll share my solution if I have time to make it :D! Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: I will also think of a way to make it work for all lines at once... maybe by returning a 2D matrice of [True, False] representing all lines intersection. Since my data are relatively small (~2500 lines in average), working with a 2500 * 2500 matrix should be faster than just looping. Maybe by creating one matrix for ds, then converting all values to u, then performing comparison using native pandas functions. I'll have to think about it.