# Group intersecting lines together

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Hello,

I am trying to group a bunch of lines that collides together. For example, if line A collides with line B, line B collides with line C, but line A doesn't collide with line C. I want them all together.

I've tried to utilise the properties of sets so I only have a unique solution and avoid duplicates. I also try to make it somewhat fast. The lines data I have is a list of floats: [x1, y1, x2, y2].

```
all_lines = lines.tolist()
lines_combinations = list()

for l in all_lines:
    #Find if the potential line already belongs to a group in line_combination
    remove_list_l = False  #is line (l) in a group in lines_combination
    remove_list_ol = False #is other line (ol) in a group in lines_combination
    line_group = False;

    for j in lines_combinations: #Iterate through all combination found already
        if tuple(l) in j:
            line_group = j
            remove_list_l = True
    if not line_group:
        line_group = {tuple(l)}
    
    #Remove a from the total line list 
    all_lines.remove(l)

    #Iterate through all potential lines
    for ol in all_lines:
        if check_collision(l, ol, px): 
            #If collision, check if k is in another group
            for k in lines_combinations: 
                 if tuple(ol) in k:
                     #If true, append both groups together
                     line_group.union(k)
                     replace_list_ol = True
            if not replace_list_ol:
                line_group.add(tuple(ol))
            
    #Remove both groups and add the new joint one
    if remove_list_l:   
        lines_combinations.remove(j)
    if replace_list_ol:
         if j != k:
             lines_combinations.remove(k)
    
    lines_combinations.append(line_group)
```

The problem is that it doesn't work too well, and that it is slow... For example in the picture below: [image: picture]

The algorithm could not merge all white lines and all brown line together while they clearly intersects (There is also some pink lines under the whites that should also belong to the group). I don't know if this is because I have the duplicated the line in different group or if the algorithm fails somewhere else. Ultimately I would love to have any line appear once in one unique group so I can avoid duplicates. I can't see where I went wrong in the algorithm...

I would love to advise on how to do it and make it faster! Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**: Hello everyone, I was able to solve my problem by replacing the line "line_group.union(k)" by "line_group = line_group.union(k)". So it works!!

However the processing time is about 30s per picture... it takes way too much time. I'm looking for advices on possible optimisation!

**EDIT 2**: You can find the data I am training my algorithm here:
[lines.txt](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pv1TfFmyPfZAlU-O7OFwCD46M816uqiy?usp=sharing)
I've exported it as a pd.DataFrame so you can load it easily! I've also added the check_collision.py script I am using to find the intersections. Very similar to the answer from M Oehm here: [stack-overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673454/find-if-segment-comes-within-distance-of-another-one/66677796?noredirect=1#comment117963206_66677796). But with the edit from collinearity.

Turns out I have problems with either the collision script or the sorting algorithm because I have groups plotted together that should not belong together.

Like the plot of one group below:
[image: Plot of one unique group, there should be 4 different groups]

Comment: I have the feeling that `lines_combination` should be a set, not a list, so that lookups and removals are O(1). You should probably also partition your space, so that collisions are checked only for lines in the vicinity.

Comment: I've tried because it seemed the best way to do it. However, it seems I cannot create a set of sets in Python. I get the Error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'" when doing list_combination.add(line_group).

Comment: The running time of 30s isn't useful without knowing the size of the problem. How many lines does a picture typically have? Do you have an example data set that you could share?

Comment: It depends on the picture. Here it was 2500 lines. First thing I plan on doing is to do Matrix calculations instead. Test one line vs all others in one go using arrays so I don't have to do ~ 2500 * 2500 loops. I wonder if there are ways to test several lines vs several lines in one go too.

Comment: Well, I've written an answer about that: Use a sweepline, which is easy to implement. Use The more efficient Bentley-Ottmann if you need to be faster. Use a graphic library with BO algo, if that's still not enough. (The sweepline with 2500 lines should be fast enough, especially since most of your lnes are short.)  You can use the results to fill in a SIMD matrix, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement a variation of union-find here. You can google for more details. You need to use O(n) extra space where n is lines number. When two lines intersect instead of collecting them into a set just mark that they both belong to the same group. so if a & b intersect a will be root of b. Now if b & c intersect root c is the root of b which is nothing but a. Now if two lines have the same root that means they are in the same group.

1. Initialize this extra space with the line number itself. i.e at the beginning every node is its own root. `rarr = [0,1,2]`
2. get all the intersections. (l1,l2), (l1,l3).
3. For every intersection mark the root of second as the root of first.

   rarr[l2] = root(l1).
4. root of an element is - get the parent of the intersection till is staying in its own index.

   root(x){

   while(rarr[x] != x)
   x = rarr[x];

   return rarr[x];
   }

Comment: This did not really work. Could you please confirm that my implementation is correct. This is the code and the picture that results from it: https://imgur.com/a/CJbwQxQ.

Comment: You can't just set `rarr[j] = root(i)`, you must join the two lists at the root: `rarr[root(j)] = root(i)`. Now all nodes whose root was `j` will now have the root `i` (because they go through `j` first.)

Answer (score 0):

Due to my poor python practice, I left a MATHEMATICA script which is I hope, an implementation for the required algorithm

First producing data

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = 100;
points = Table[RandomReal[{0, 100}, 2], {i, 1, n}];
segs = Table[{points[[k]] + RandomReal[{-20, 20}, 2], points[[k]] + RandomReal[{-20, 20}, 2]}, {k, 1, n}];
grseg = Table[ParametricPlot[x segs[[k, 1]] + (1 - x) segs[[k, 2]], {x, 0, 1}], {k, 1, n}];
Show[grseg, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
```

Follows the processing

```
Clear[intersects]
intersects[i_, j_, segs_] := Module[{si, sj, xi, xj, xi0, xj0, sol},
  si = segs[[i]]; sj = segs[[j]]; 
  sol = Solve[Thread[xi si[[1]] + (1 - xi) si[[2]] == xj sj[[1]] + (1 - xj) sj[[2]]], {xi, xj}]; 
  {xi0, xj0} = {xi, xj} /. sol[[1]]; 
  If[0 <= xi0 && xi0 <= 1 && 0 <= xj0 && xj0 <= 1, Return[True], Return[False]]
]

list = {};
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
 For[j = 1, j < i, j++,
  If[i != j && intersects[i, j, segs], AppendTo[list, Sort[{i, j}]]]
  ]
]

list = Union[list];
nl = Length[list];
LIST = {};
For[i = 1, i <= nl, i++,
 lista = list[[i]];
 For[j = 1, j <= nl, j++,
  If[i != j && Length[Intersection[lista, list[[j]]]] > 0, lista = Union[lista, list[[j]]]];
  ];
 AppendTo[LIST, lista];
]

LIST = Union[LIST];
nf = -2;
nL = -1;
While[nL != nf,
 LISTF = {};
 nL = Length[LIST];
 For[i = 1, i <= nL, i++,
  lista = LIST[[i]];
  For[j = 1, j <= nL, j++,
   If[i != j && Length[Intersection[lista, LIST[[j]]]] > 0, lista = Union[lista, LIST[[j]]]];
  ];
  AppendTo[LISTF, lista]
  ];
  LISTF = Union[LISTF];
  nf = Length[LISTF];
  LIST = LISTF
]

LISTF
```

And a final plot

```
listgr = {};
For[k = 1, k <= nf, k++, ns = Length[LISTF[[k]]];
 inds = LISTF[[k]];
 ni = Length[inds];
 color = RGBColor[RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}]];
 AppendTo[listgr,Table[ParametricPlot[x segs[[inds[[j]], 1]] + (1 - x) segs[[inds[[j]], 2]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {color, Thick}], {j, 1, ni}]]]
Show[grseg, listgr, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

NOTE

The python version follows.

```
from random import seed
from random import random
from operator import add
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib import collections  as mc

seed(2)

# First producing data

n       = 100
span1   = 100
span2   = 15
centers = []

for _ in range(n):
    centers.append([span1*random(),span1*random()])

segments = []
for i in range(n):
    var1 = [2*span2*(random()-0.5),2*span2*(random()-0.5)]
    var2 = [2*span2*(random()-0.5),2*span2*(random()-0.5)]
    segments.append([list(map(add,centers[i],var1)),list(map(add,centers[i],var2))])

def intersect(s1,s2):
    c1 = list(map(lambda i, j: i-j,s1[1],s1[0]))
    c2 = list(map(lambda i, j: i-j,s2[1],s2[0]))
    c0 = list(map(lambda i, j: i-j,s2[0],s1[0]))
    c11 = np.dot(c1,c1)
    c22 = np.dot(c2,c2)
    c12 = np.dot(c1,c2)
    c01 = np.dot(c0,c1)
    c02 = np.dot(c0,c2)
    discr = c12*c12-c11*c22
    x=(c12*c02-c01*c22)/discr
    y=(c11*c02-c01*c12)/discr
    if ((0 < x) and (x < 1) and (0 < y) and (y < 1)):
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

def intersection(lst1, lst2): 
    return list(set(lst1).intersection(lst2)) 

def union(lst1, lst2): 
    final_list = list(set(lst1) | set(lst2)) 
    return final_list 

list_intersects = []
for i in range(n):
    si = segments[i]
    for j in range(i):
        sj = segments[j]
        if (i !=  j) and intersect(si,sj):
            list_intersects.append(sorted([i,j]))

print(list_intersects)
        
nl = len(list_intersects)
print(nl)

LIST = []
for i in range(nl):
    lista = list_intersects[i]
    for j in range(nl):
        if (i != j) and len(intersection(lista,list_intersects[j])) > 0:
            lista = sorted(union(lista,list_intersects[j]))
        if (lista not in LIST):
            LIST.append(lista)
print(LIST)

nF = -2
nL = -1
while (nL != nF):
    LISTF = []
    nL = len(LIST)
    for i in range(nL):
        lista = LIST[i]
        for j in range(nL):
            if (i != j) and len(intersection(lista,LIST[j])) > 0:
                lista = sorted(union(lista,LIST[j]))
        if (lista not in LISTF):
            LISTF.append(lista)
    nF = len(LISTF)
    LIST = LISTF
            
# final groups
    
(fig, ax) = pl.subplots(1)
c = np.array([(1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 1)])       
nF = len(LISTF)
for i in range(nF):
    #print(">> ",LISTF[i])
    inds = LISTF[i]
    bunch = []
    for j in range(len(inds)):
        bunch.append(segments[inds[j]])
    #print(bunch)
    lc = mc.LineCollection(bunch, colors=c[i % 3], linewidths=2)
    ax.add_collection(lc)    
ax.autoscale()
ax.margins(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**To make it correct**: Python sets are the right data structure for sets, of course, but here, where you have to merge two sets often and delete the one that was merged, the common disjoint set implementation already suggested by Krishna and Caesareo might be better suited:

- The lines are organized in a directed graph, where each line has one outgoing edge, the parent.
- Each set is identified by its "root". The parent of a root is itself.
- At the beginning, each line is in its own set.
- The root can be found by following the parent until a root is found.
- Two sets can be joined by joining their roots, that is by making the first root the parent of the second.

This representation is good for quickly joining sets. It is not suited for iterating across all elements, which is something you only have to do once at the end. The more sets are joind, the longer the chains in the graph become. There is a trick to replace the parent of a non-root with the root after finding the root, so that evetually, the root will be the direct parent of all lines in the set.

This can be coded in a `Line` class:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, p, q):
        self.p = p
        self.q = q
        self.parent = self
        
    def __repl__(self):
        return "Line(%r, %r)" % (self.p, self.q)
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.p, self.q)[index]
        
    def join(self, other):
        sp = self.root()
        op = other.root()

        op.parent = sp

    def root(self):
        if self.parent == self:
            return self

        self.parent = self.parent.root()
        
        return self.parent
```

The method `l.root()` finds the associated root node and `l.join(k)` joins two sets. The base algorithm then is:

```
for i, l in enumerate(lines):           # find intersections
    g = l.root()

    for k in lines[i + 1:]:
        if g != k.root() and intersects(l, k):
            l.join(k)

groups = {}

for l in lines:                         # find groups
    h = l.root()
    
    groups.setdefault(h, []);
    groups[h] += [l]
```

This will test all possible intersections in a triangle. It won't test lines that are already in the same group, but it's still O(*N* ²).

**To make it faster**: One way to speed up spatial finding or matching algorithms such as yours is to reduce the search space. There are several ways, buckets or kd trees for points are examples.

In your case, where you have long lines spanning nearly all the space, you could use a sweep line. Say you scan your image in positive *y* direction from bottom to top.  Create two "events" for each line: One for the lower node, one for the upper node node. Each event has a *y* coordinate, a reference to a line and a type, which is one of "enter"  or "leave":

```
enter(line, min(y) − Δ)
leave(line, max(y) + Δ)
```

Sort all points by one the *y* coordinate. Create an active set and iterate through the sorted array. When you hit an enter event, test all lines in the active set against the line, then add the line to the active set. When you hit a leave event, remove the line from the active set.

This will make you look only at a small slice of the search space.

```
sweep = []
delta = 1.0

for l in lines:
    p, q = l
    
    sweep.append((min(p.y, q.y) - delta, True, l))
    sweep.append((max(p.y, q.y) + delta, False, l))

sweep.sort()    
active = set()

for x, activate, line in sweep:    
    if activate:    
        for other in active:
            if intersects(line, other):
                line.join(other)

        active.add(line)
    else:  
        active.remove(line)
```

Sorting the sets into groups is as above. (I don't check whether the two collision candidates are in the same group, because testing that seems to reduce the performance slightly, but that may depend on the input set.)

**Making it even faster**: Other algorithms, for example the [Bentley-Ottmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) algorithm, imrpove on the sweepline algorithm by also partitioning the active set in the perpendicular direction.

Also implementing the above "simple" sweepline algorithm in C gives a huge speedup. (I guess much of it is because of good locality of the data.)

So if you want to be really fast, look for a graphics library that has a Python interface and that implements the Bentley-Ottmann algorithms or better.

Comment: I've been looking at your answer. It turns out that l.group() does not exists in your Line class. Do you mean l.root() instead?

Comment: Yes, it must be l.root(). Sorry about that.

Comment: This should also be g != l.root() in the if statement before l.join(k). Also are you confident in the robustness of this solution? The lines are still wrongly grouped and I am at the limits of my python knowledge. I am trying to determine if the problem comes from my intersection function or if the algorithm still group wrongly.

Comment: I renamed the `root` method after I introduced `group` as name for a group, so every time it's `.group()` it should be `.root()`. (Your code has the same problem with `remove_`and `replace`, by the way.)

Comment: I'm pretty confident of my solution, yes. In my test, I've used a simple intersection algorithm, not one with a radius. I've seen that you have made the data available. I might look into it later.

Comment: On the other hand, I might not -- I don't have a Google account.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's [my implementation](https://ideone.com/eIxwTp). It prints a Postscript file vor viszalization. For 2500 lines, it takes about a second with the sweepline approach, about 25s with the naive approach. (There was a typo in my "slow" code, I'll fix that.)

Comment: Thanks for the script. I think I have an issue with my collision script then. Here is the data if you are still interested in it: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/25b0cffc7c50d02892848ad5d74f094320210330142104/901686

Comment: I haven't looked too closely at your implementation yet, but for what it's worth, [here](https://pastebin.com/4N19sz3p)'s my working script for your data. (I had to adjust my collision search a bit.) It finds the collisions in a bit more than 3s. [This C program](https://pastebin.com/1ehet47r) does the same, but in a fraction of a second.